# Issue passing return of a function to textView in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am currently trying to calculate loan and want to get a monthly fee a user need to pay.
The calculation happends in a shared ViewModel and I want to send the return to a TextView.

But I only get a Null when the app build the view. Not sure how to call the function and then display the result.

[image]

AnnuitetViewModel.kt

```
fun getMonthlyPayment(): Double? {

    val monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate?.div(100)
    val x = monthlyInterestRate?.let { loanAmount?.times(it) }
    val y =
        numberOfYears?.let { Math.pow((1 + annualInterestRate!!).toDouble(), it.toDouble()) }
            ?.div((Math.pow((1 + annualInterestRate!!).toDouble(), numberOfYears!!.toDouble()) - 1))
    val monthlyPayment = y?.let { x?.times(it) }
    return monthlyPayment
}
```

fragment_annuitet_plan.xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTest4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@{`` + viewmodel.monthlyPayment}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.79" />
```

AnnuitetPLanFragment.kt

```
class AnnuitetPlanFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAnnuitetPlanBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var viewModel: AnnuitetViewModel

    private val AnnuitetViewModel: AnnuitetViewModel by activityViewModels()


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAnnuitetPlanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)




        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[AnnuitetViewModel::class.java]

        AnnuitetViewModel.antallRenter.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { progressRenter ->
            binding.tvTest.text = progressRenter.toString()
        }

        AnnuitetViewModel.progressAar.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { progressAar ->
            binding.tvTest2.text = progressAar.toString()
        }

        AnnuitetViewModel.loanNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { loanNumber ->
            binding.tvTest3.text = loanNumber.toString()

        }
        binding.tilbakeTilAnnuitet.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetPlanFragment_to_annuitetFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you binding the view model inside fragment_annuitet_plan.xml?

Comment: Yes. Are using databinding.<data> with path</data>

Comment: You have so many nullables...if any of them are null, you will get a null result. I don't use data binding, but I assume if you bind to a static function instead of LiveData, it only calls it once when the view is created, which might be before your parameters are all set. So I think you need to do two things. Avoid nullable properties wherever possible because they make your code very likely to silently fail. And change `getMonthlyPayment()` into a LiveData that is refreshed when any of the properties it depends on are changed.